# Linux fopen() syntax for samba share

Tags: c, linux, fopen, samba

I am trying to use the following syntax for fopen() to access a samba share.

```
FILE *of = fopen("smb://sambadevice/folder/filename.txt", "w");
```

but this is not working (errno = 2).

Does anyone know the correct syntax for a samba share?

PS - if I type "smb://sambadevice/folder" into Dolphin, it opens the folder.

Comment: `fopen` and the underlying `open` only work for files on mounted filesystems. They do not understand SMB URLs. GNOME has **GVfs** to mount remote filesystems such as SMB shares locally as a subdirectory of `${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/gvfs`. The KDE equivalent is **KioFuse**, but that's a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks @Ian Abbott for that insight.

Comment: In the past (I no longer use KDE), I've used **Smb4K** for mounting SMB shares in KDE. That still seems to be supported, so worth investigating.

Comment: when the call to `fopen()` fails (returns a NULL) then should immediately call `perror()` so the text reason the system thinks the error occurred is output to `stderr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fopen` doesn't understand *any* syntax.  There are no special filename forms you can pass it in order to access anything special, nothing other than an ordinary filename path in (what appears to be) the local filesystem.

When you pass a pathname to `fopen`, typically it doesn't parse or inspect the pathname string in any way; it just passes it on to the underlying `open` system call.  And then `open` doesn't do much more than a very basic parse of the pathname, either: all it does is split it on `/` characters so that it can walk the path (work down through any directories and subdirectories) to find the requested file.  This is in keeping with an important tenet of the Unix philosophy, namely "everything's a file".

This absolutely does *not* mean, however, that there's no way to access Samba-mounted fileshares using a C program that calls `fopen`.  If you want to access Samba-mounted fileshares, you need to figure out how to *mount* them in the local filesystem.  There are lots of ways to do this.  Me, I use the command `mount.cifs`.  People in the comments have also mentioned `GVfs`, `KioFuse`, and `Smb4K`.

Once you've got your Samba file share mounted (or, similarly, once you've got *any* resource mounted) as if it were a file or directory in the local filesystem, you can access via its pathname just as if -- well, just as if it were a file or directory in the local filesystem.  (And of course you can access it via any tool or application, whether or not it's a C program calling `fopen`.)

So on a Unix or Linux system you typically won't see any explicit `smb://` syntax in the pathname you open.  Typically the pathname you open will start with `/mnt` or `/cifs` or `/home/myname/.gvfs` -- that is, wherever in the filesystem the Samba share has been mounted.

Comment: Typically on linux, one will use autofs to automount smb shares under /cifs, so could use a path like "/cifs/sambadevice/folder/filename.txt".  Most linux distributions come with autofs/smb support turned off by default as it has some security implications (if you don't trust other devices on the local network, it is somewhat unsafe to do).